# How to change license key for TFS 2018

Tags: tfs, microsoft-test-manager

I am new to TFS admin configuration. I have installed a TFS 2018 in one of the server and now facing connectivity issue to MTM.
So I came to know that I should have a valid license and I also got the license.

Can anyone tell me**Where or How to upgrade my TFS 2018 License**

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

> To license TFS 2018, you’ll need a **TFS server license** and a
>   Windows operating system license (Windows Server is best) for each
>   machine running TFS, plus **a client access license for each person
>   connecting to TFS**. Client access licenses (CALs) aren’t required for
>   people who just access work items – assign them “Stakeholder” access,
>   which is free.
>
> Extensions to TFS such as **Test Manager**, Package Management, and
>   Private Pipelines require an additional purchase. Some TFS Extensions
>   are included with **Visual Studio Enterprise subscriptions** and many
>   others are free. Paid extensions can also be purchased monthly, no
>   Visual Studio subscription is required.

In your case, for every MSDN subscription that you own, you will also have a TFS server licenses. So, theoretically, you could install as many TFS servers as you have MSDN subscriptions.

> To use the features MTM, you must have either a **Visual Studio
>   Enterprise subscription**, or have **installed the Test Manager
>   extension** available from Visual Studio Marketplace.

More details please refer: [**Connect Microsoft Test Manager to your team project and test plan**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/manual-test/mtm/connect-microsoft-test-manager-to-your-team-project-and-test-plan?view=vsts)

Besides, If you want to double confirm this and  know more information about TFS license, you could call 1-800-426-9400, Monday through Friday, 6:00 A.M. to 6:00 P.M. (Pacific Time) to speak directly to a Microsoft licensing specialist, and you can get more detail information from there. Worldwide customers can use the Guide to Worldwide Microsoft Licensing Sites to find contact information in their locations: http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/